# Find Discrete & Continuous variable influence on an outcome

Tags: classification, correlation, feature-selection, feature-engineering

I want to find out from a given data set the influence of following type of variable on outcome.
1. Continuous variable
2. Discrete variable

E.g. I am selling watches and watch has set of discrete variable like type, style, ageclass,brand which may influence what purchaser is looking...
There is another set of continuous variable like discount given or pricing, offers made that could influence. This also means we need to know correlation between these.

How do we identify dynamically these influencers and identify the model to predict right product to users ?